# How to get GCM Notifications in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I am a beginner in iOS. In my project I want to get GCM notifications for that I have written some code but it shows exception and my code is as following :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>
#import "GGLInstanceID.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =  (UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |  UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =  [UIUserNotificationSettings
                                             settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    _registrationHandler = ^(NSString *registrationToken, NSError *error){
        if (registrationToken != nil) {
            weakSelf.registrationToken = registrationToken;
            NSLog(@"Registration Token: %@", registrationToken);
            NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"registrationToken":registrationToken};
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:weakSelf.registrationKey
                                                                object:nil
                                                              userInfo:userInfo];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Registration to GCM failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"error":error.localizedDescription};
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:weakSelf.registrationKey
                                                                object:nil
                                                              userInfo:userInfo];
        }
    };

    return YES;
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig]];

    _registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                             kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderID
                                                        scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                      options:_registrationOptions
                                                      handler:_registrationHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {


    NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);
    // This works only if the app started the GCM service
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

}
```

But it's shows Exception like

> `unresolved identifier "_registrationHandler"` and `"weakSelf" in
>   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method` and it exception in
>   `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method like 
>   `unresolved identifier "_registrationOptions"`.

Please help me someone

Comment: is the `_registrationHandler` variable even defined somewhere? same for weakSelf

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client i just followed this tutorial

Comment: if you know better way plese post that

Comment: First of all, this is Objective-C, not Swift (I changed the tag). Secondly, you are not defining those variables anywhere which is why you are getting this error - and you not understanding this shows you likely don't know Objective-C in the first place. I'd recommend doing a simple Objective-C tutorial like the one on apple.com: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

Here I've refactored your code and it should work now.

```
static NSString *const INSTANCE_ID_REGISTRATION_NOTIF_KEY = @"instance-id-token";
static NSString *const GCM_SENDER_ID = @"<your sender id>"; // @"123456"

@interface AppDelegate ()

    @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) GGLInstanceIDTokenHandler registrationHandler;
    @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *registrationToken;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =  (UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |  UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =  [UIUserNotificationSettings
                                                 settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

        return YES;
    }


    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

        [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:[GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig]];

        NSDictionary *registrationOptions = @{
            kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
            kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES
        };

        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        GGLInstanceIDTokenHandler handler = ^(NSString *registrationToken, NSError *error){
            typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;

            NSDictionary *userInfo;
            if (registrationToken != nil) {
                strongSelf.registrationToken = registrationToken;
                NSLog(@"Registration Token: %@", registrationToken);
                userInfo = @{ @"registrationToken" : registrationToken };
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Registration to GCM failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                userInfo = @{ @"error" : error.localizedDescription };
            }

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:INSTANCE_ID_REGISTRATION_NOTIF_KEY
                                                                object:nil
                                                              userInfo:userInfo];

        };

        [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:GCM_SENDER_ID
                                                            scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                          options:registrationOptions
                                                          handler:handler];
    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
        NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);
        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        [[GCMService sharedInstance] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
    }

@end
```

PS: As @Epaga commented above you should really try to start off with a simple obj-c tutorial because your compiler issues were very trivial.